# Apache version viewer command httpd -v is not working

Tags: bash, rhel, apache-httpd

`/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -v` command is working on my server but `httpd -v` is not working. it says command not found. How can i fix this so that `httpd -v` show me the apache version.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -v` and just `httpd -v` is that in the first case the system runs a very specific executable while in the second case it searches the executable in the directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. But eventually this is going to be the very same executable(*)

To add the required directory to the path, you can use:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/
```

(*) unless you have installed several instances of `httpd`... But in that case what is going to be important is the version of `httpd` which is run as a service, in which case you would have to find the declaration of the service, that likely has the full path to the `httpd` executable to be used by the service.

Comment: Thank You.. when  Iam restarting the server then it is not working

Comment: The "server" doesn't the PATH you use. The server definition should have the full path to the executable (and the path you have is strange... doesn't look installed correctly).